# What's the meaning of the number following the @?

Tags: intellij-idea

What's the meaning of the number following the @? {SimpleJobService@7359},i mean the "7359"? It ain't seem to be the hashcode, i can't say for sure.
[screenshot of WATCHES pannel when debugging in idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIXw2.png)